# Infinite cuboids In space

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory

Given an arbitrary $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, can we always find infinite sets $A, B, C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that either $A \times B \times C \subseteq X$ or $A \times B \times C \subseteq (\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus X)$? Here $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the real line.

I believe that the answer should be well known (and positive?), but I don't see it.

Comment: What restrictions are you putting on your set $X$? Is the topology of ${\mathbb R}$ relevant to your question or not?

Comment: None. Only cardinality is relevant.

Comment: The answer should be negative, by diagonalizing on two copies of the list (well-ordering) of cuboids.  There may even be an explicit description (a pencil of diagonal lines, perhaps?).  Gerhard "Sierpinski Probably Solved A Generalization" Paseman, 2018.01.04.

Comment: But there are many many more cuboids than points ($2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ vs $2^{\aleph_0}$), so [transfinite] diagonalisation won't work here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is Problem 28 in the paper Unsolved problems in set theory of Erdos and Hajnal https://old.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1971-28.pdf (at least if CH holds). In an 1982 paper https://old.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1982-24.pdf Erdos reports that Mills and Prikry solved it negatively, but I could not locate their paper.

Comment: Thanks for the references. Do you think that the problem is still open?

Comment: Will try to check it.